# Unable to interact with firebase real time database emulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently having issues trying to interact with the real-time database emulator. The emulator is up and running on port 9030, and am able to interact with it via the emulator ui.

My firebase.js is set up like so (config values removed):

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/database"

export const config = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL:
    "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
}

function initFirebase() {
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config)
  }
}

initFirebase()

const rtdb = firebase.database()

console.log(location.hostname)
if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
  console.log("emulator db")
  // Point to the RTDB emulator running on localhost.
  rtdb.useEmulator("localhost", 9030)
}

const auth = firebase.auth

export default firebase
export { rtdb, auth }
```

The `console.log("emulator db")` is being hit, and from what I can tell from the docs this is the correct way to be using the method `useEmulator()`?

Any data I try to read/write comes from/to the prod database hosted on firebase itself, not the emulator.

I feel like I'm missing something painfully obvious.

For reference, my firebase.json:

````
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9010
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 9020
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9030
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 9040
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: what do you have written in your `export const config databaseURL:  " ",` ?

Comment: Have you tried changing the `const` keyword to `var` before the initialisation?

Comment: Have you see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkgvFNPdiEs ?

Answer (score 1):

@keremistan's comment put me onto the right track by sending me to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkgvFNPdiEs.

This is mentioned nowhere in Google's docs. The trick they use in the video to modify the config variable to connect to the right URL. No mention of `useEmulator()`.

```js
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_MEASUREMENT_ID,
  }
  
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    const emulatorUrl = `http://localhost:9000?ns=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FB_PROJECT_ID}`;
    firebaseConfig.databaseURL = emulatorUrl
  }
```